# Is it possible to use OpenCL in Windows EC7?

Tags: arm, opencl, windows-embedded-compact

We have a system with computation devices that support openCL (ARM CPU with NEON, GPU, DSP, FPGA).

Is it possible to use OpenCL when running Windows EC7?
What OpenCL SDK could be used? Can anyone provide a link to a successful project or any description?

Answer (score 0):

`OpenCL` is mostly a GPU technology while `NEON` is ARM's brand name for a CPU technology about [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simd). So this means you don't get OpenCL just because your ARM core supports NEON.

Comment: I didn't express myself very clearly (I'll edit it). The question for us is whether we can use openCL on the CPU AND other devices of our system (GPU, DSPs etc.). So, my point is, we do have devices that support openCL, but the question now is whether it can be used if the operating system is Windows EC7. Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any Windows Embedded Compact 7 conformant implementations of OpenCL listed on the Khronos [Conformant Products](http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products) page. There are some Linux (Ubuntu) and Android ARM implementations listed there though.